# Subprocess no output when running a shell

Tags: python, subprocess

I tried to run a system shell in Python subprocess module:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("/bin/bash", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
print(p.communicate())
```

However, it printed `(b'', b'')`
I tried other shells too, but they all failed to work. (Zsh, Sh, and FiSH)
How can I get the output? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I think it should print the prompt, like "~/directory $"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me as you would expect I guess.

```
(base) tzane:~/python_test$ python test_1.py
whereis ls
exit
(b'ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz\n', b'')
(base) tzane:~/python_test$
```

You are not getting any output if you are not telling bash to output anything. Calling `.wait()` with pipes can cause deadlocks so I would do something like this instead

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("/bin/bash", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    print(p.communicate(timeout=30))
except TimeoutExpired:
    p.kill()
    print(p.commnunicate())
```

as suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) or just use `subprocess.run` if you don't have to interact with the subprocess and you just want to catch the output.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to put something in stdin before reading the stdout, right?

Comment: @AndyZhang In the case of bash, yes, because bash doesn't output anything unless you tell it to. If you were to run a subprocess command like this `p = subprocess.Popen("echo monty", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` you would get `(b'monty\n', b'')` without having to write anything to stdin.